# La clave externa FK_DETALLE_FACTURAS_ARTICULOS hace referencia a una columna no valida 'CodArt_Ar' en la tabla a la que se hace referencia 'Articulos'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas estoy realizando las relaciones de las tablas de una base de datos donde existe una tabla articulos y otra facturas. Cree una tercer tabla intermedia llamada DetalleFacturas para que pueda haber mas de un articulo en una factura.

Tabla Articulos:

```
CREATE TABLE Articulos
(
CodArt_Ar CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
Nombre_Art varchar(25) NOT NULL,
Stock int DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL ,
PuntoPedido varchar(25) NOT NULL,
ValorU DECIMAL(8,2) DEFAULT '0,00' NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_ARTICULOS PRIMARY KEY (CodArt_Ar)
)
GO
```

Tabla Facturas:

```
CREATE TABLE Facturas
(
NumFact_F CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
TotalFact_F DECIMAL (8,2) DEFAULT '0,00' NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_FACTURAS PRIMARY KEY(NumFact_F)
)
GO
```

Tabla DetalleFacturas:

```
CREATE TABLE DetalleFacturas
(
NumFact_DF CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
CodArt_DF CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
ValorU_DF DECIMAL (8,2) DEFAULT '0,00' NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_DETALLE_FACTURAS PRIMARY KEY(NumFact_DF),
CONSTRAINT FK_DETALLES_FACTURAS_ARTICULOS FOREIGN KEY (CodArt_DF) REFERENCES Articulos (CodArt_Ar),
CONSTRAINT FK_DETALLE_FACTURAS_ARTICULOS FOREIGN KEY (NumFact_DF) REFERENCES Facturas (NumFact_F)

)
GO
```

En la relación de la tabla DetalleFacturas donde hago la clave foranea de CodArt_DF con CodArt_Art dice que estoy haciendo una referencia a una columna no valida la cual es 'CodArt_Ar' de la tabla 'Articulos'
No se si las relaciones estan mal o es un error de tipeo lo cual no creo.

Comment: Tus tablas, vacíalas, primero crea los indices y forens, después las pueblas.

Comment: Así como está escrito me corre bien, seguro pegaste tu código tal cual?

Comment: @Srsole en el código mostrado se están creando las tablas?, por ende están vacías

Comment: He replicado tu código en un servidor con MariaDB 10 y no tengo ningún error. La sintáxis es correcta.

Comment: @Juan me corrió el código aunque marque el error, debe haber sido porque las tablas no tenían datos insertados. Aunque con estas relaciones no me deja tener mas de un artículo en una misma factura lo que me parece raro porque las relaciones están bien.

Comment: No, ese error no es por no tener datos en las tablas

Comment: ¿El problema es que no te deja tener mas de un artículo en una misma factura? Entonces el problema está en tu llave primaria de la tabla de detalles. Necesitas quitarla o agregar la columna de artículo para que sea una llave compuesta.